# Compilation error due to missing property on JSX element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am using material-ui, I have a Slider element:

```
<Slider ... sliderStyle={{}} ...>
```

I get the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'sliderStyle' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Slider> & SliderProps & { children?: ReactElement<...'.
```

I guess the definition file is not up to date. How can I ignore this error ?

Comment: The [current `material-ui`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui) version is `0.15.4`. The [current .d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/material-ui/material-ui.d.ts) file version is `0.15.1`. So it is not up to date, but are you sure that this `sliderStyle` should exist in the [`SliderProps` interface](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/material-ui/material-ui.d.ts#L1328)?

Comment: I believe it should, see here: http://www.material-ui.com/v0.15.3/#/components/slider
This line:
`sliderStyle   object   Override the inline-styles of the inner slider element.`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the `sliderStyle` was added to the `SilderProps` interface in version `0.15.2`, as it's not there [in `0.15.1`](http://www.material-ui.com/v0.15.1/#/components/slider#properties).

You can [augmentate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) it:

```
interface SliderProps extends React.Props<Slider> {
    sliderStyle: { [key: string]: any };
}
```

And by that you add this property to the interface.

You can also just change the `.d.ts` file you have manually until there's an update to the next version which should then have this property anyhow.

---

#### Edit

You'll need to import and augment the `SliderProps` and not the `Slider` itself because the `sliderStyle` is part of the props.
Should be:

```
import SliderProps from 'material-ui/Slider';

interface SliderProps {
    sliderStyle: { [key: string]: any };
}
```

I haven't tested it, but that's the idea.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details on how to use this? From what I understood this creates a new interface with a new `sliderStyle` parameter. But how do I use it in JSX ? Should I create a `<SliderProps/>` element ?

Comment: No, the purpose of augmentation is to add properties to existing interfaces, so if that should add the `sliderStyle` property to the existing `SliderProps` interface which is used in the jsx. The attributes you enter inside the `<Silder />` are these `SliderProps` .

Comment: So you're saying I can do this: `import Slider from 'material-ui/Slider';`, then the sniped you gave, and finally I can have `<Slider sliderStyle={{}}/>` in my render function? For some reasons I still have `error TS2339`.

Comment: Check my modified answer

Comment: Still impossible for me to make it work. If I follow your edit then the compiler complains that `SliderProps` is defined twice and that he cannot find the name `Slider`. All the resources out there are presenting module augmentation the same way, which does not really fit what I want to do. But your answer seems to point in the right direction. I just need to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Cast a variable to any, set the value to Slider and then the attribute checking will be bypassed.

```
import { Slider } from "material-ui";
const MySlider: any = Slider;
```